# How I can extract a subset of months from all NetCDF files in one directory

Tags: python, time, extract, netcdf, percentile

I need to calculate the 90th percentile based on temperature data for 1961-1990. I have 30 NETCDF files and every file includes daily data for one year. I need to calculate the percentile (90th) for special Lat, Long while considering just summer days out of all 30 years of daily data. I need also consider the years when February has 29 days. When I run my code it just considered the first summer (summer 1961) and cannot consider all summer days with each other.

```
data = xr.open_mfdataset('/Tmax-2m/Control/*.nc')

time = data.variables['time']
lon = data.variables['lon'][:]
lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
tmax = data.variables['tmax'][:]

df = data.sel(lat=39.18,lon=-95.57, method='nearest')
time2=df.variables['time'][151:243]
dg=df.sel (time=time2, method = 'nearest')
print np.percentile (dg.tmax, 90)
```

I tried this way but it calculate the percentile for every summer of every year:

```
splits=[151,516,881,1247,1612,1977,2342,2708,3073,3438,3803,4169,4534,4899,5264,5630,5995,6360,6725,7091,7456,7821,8186,8552,8917,9282,9647,10013,10378,10743]
t0=92
result=[]
for i in splits:
    time3=df.variables['time'][i:(i+t0)]
    dg=df.sel(time=time3, method ='nearest')  
    result.append(np.percentile (dg.tmax, 90))

np.savetxt("percentile1.csv", result, fmt="%s")
```

Comment: Can't you just take the mean of result?

Comment: No because its extreme values and cannot be averaged.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use CDO for this task?  (If you are running under linux this is easy, if you are on windows, you probably need to install it under cygwin)

You can merge the 30 files into one timeseries like this:

```
cdo mergetime file_y*.nc timeseries.nc
```

here the * is a wildcard for the year (1961, 1962 etc) in the filename that I assuming is file_y1961.nc file_y1962.nc etc...  adopt as appropriate. timeseries.nc is the output file.

and then calculate the seasonal percentiles like this :

```
cdo yseaspctl,90 timeseries.nc -yseasmin timeseries.nc -yseasmax timeseries.nc percen.nc
```

percen.nc will have the seasonal percentiles in and you can extract the one for summer.

further details here: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/

Comment: Thank you but I cannot figure out how to install CDO!

Comment: Are you using linux (ubuntu, mint?) then you can do sudo apt-get install cdo  . but if you are on a windows machine you have to probably install cygwin first (there are hints on how to then install cdo on that platform on the cdo website).